# Why do I hit invalid memory after sbrk?

Tags: c, memory, sbrk

I'm trying to use the `sbrk` system call to ask for one memory page and divide that page into small blocks, but my code always hits some invalid memory:

```
void sbrkBlocks() {
    int *b = sbrk(0);
    if(sbrk(sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)) == (void *)-1) {
        printf("sbrk failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    void *bound =b + sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    while (b + 16 <=bound) {
       *b = 1;
        b+= 16;
    }
}
```

Like if I get `sbrk(0)` at `0x804d000`, the bound after `sbrk(one_page_size)` will be `0x8055000`, but the code will get a segmentation fault at `0x804e000`.

Comment: is this for an appl or a kernel module?

Comment: This is for implementing malloc, I modified my actual code so it would be easier for understaning.

Comment: On my system, `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` returns 4096, which I think is pretty typical.  If yours is the same then you have performed your bound computation wrongly: for an initial break at `0x804d000`, the new break should be at `0x804e000`, exactly where you get the segfault.

Comment: If you're implementing an allocator yourself, its usually better to stick to `char *` and `void *`. This allows you to be explicit about how large chunks are, and specify _exactly_ where to put the bits you use for book-keeping.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved, I added wrong number to bound.

Comment: If any of the answers were helpful, it is polite to mark one of them as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing your pointer arithmetic incorrectly. `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` returns the size in *bytes* of a page. Adding that `b`, which is pointer-to-int, adds `sizeof(int) * _SC_PAGESIZE` to it.

Run this:

```
int *b = sbrk(0);
printf("b = %p\n", b);
printf("PAGESIZE = %d\n", sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE));
void *bound = b + sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
printf("bound = %p\n", bound);
printf("bound - b = %d\n", (char *) bound - (char *) b);
```

You should get something like:

```
b = 0x10c37d000
PAGESIZE = 4096
bound = 0x10c37e000
bound - b = 16384
```

You're just writing past the end of the boundary you actually did allocate.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's the reason I hit the invalid memory.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, on some systems, `sbrk` doesn't return aligned pointers and you should check the actual pointer after calling `sbrk`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int *l = sbrk(0);
    sbrk(getpagesize());
    int *u = sbrk(0);  // do this to get the actual aligned pointer
    //int *u = l + getpagesize(); // may fail, may not be accurate
    printf("l=%p, u=%p\n", l, u);
    while (l + 16 < u) {
       *l  = 1;
        l += 16;
        printf("l=%p\n", l);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If he were performing an incorrectly-aligned write to valid memory -- on a system where it matters --  then wouldn't he expect to get a bus error instead of a segmentation fault?

Comment: Thank you, although that's not the cause of my problem, but I will add the check you mentioned.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Maybe... Probably. I've seen the same (bad) code generate `SIGBUS` and `SIGSEGV` depending upon what machine it ran.